# How do you issue a 404 response from a rails controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the preferred way to issue a 404 response from a rails controller action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect to a 404 in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This seems good...

```
# Rails 2 and below
render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html",  :status => 404

# Rails 3 and up
render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html",  :status => 404
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails#answer-4983354) on another question strikes me as more powerful. Bonus: it includes test code :-)

Comment: Use Rails.root.to_s instead of RAILS_ROOT in later versions of rails

Comment: @deb what difference does it make? String interpolation will call `to_s` implicitly.

Comment: Ok, [Erwin Bolwidt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/981744/erwin-bolwidt) rollback [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/779837/3) even when it [approved](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5248553). So you need to add `, :layout => false` after `:status => 404` to exclude all other layout.

Answer (score 38):

You can also

`raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

exception.

Comment: for instance by using `.find_by!` or `.first!`

Answer (score 32):

The following way was the best for me:

```
raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
```

or just

```
raise ActionController::RoutingError, 'Not Found'
```

Or there are some other solutions:
[How to redirect to a 404 in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails)

Comment: Same but simpler: `raise ActionController::RoutingError, 'Not Found'`

Answer (score 6):

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-render.htm):

```
render :file => '/path/to/some/filenotfound.rhtml', 
                status => 404, :layout => true
```

Answer (score 6):

In the ApplicationController define a method like:

```
def render_404
  render status: 404, layout: false file: Rails.root.join("public/404.html")
end
```

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 5 you can use

```
head 404
```

This will set the response code of your action to `404`. If you immediately return after this from your action method, your action will respond `404` with no actual body. This may be useful when you're developing API endpoints, but with end user HTTP requests you'll likely prefer some visible body to inform the user about the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to issue a status code on a redirect (e.g. 302), you could put this in `routes.rb`:
`get "/somewhere", to: redirect("/somewhere_else", status: 302)`.
However, this would only work for redirection, not straight up loading a page.