# Best way to handle 404 in Rails3 controllers with a DataMapper get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

It's very simple, I want to handle a normal [show] request with a call to DataMapper like I did in Merb.

With ActiveRecord I could have done this:

```
class PostsController
  def show
    @post = Post.get(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments unless @post.nil?
  end
end
```

and it handles the 404 by catching the resource's exceptions.

DataMapper instead doesn't do this automatically so right now I'm solving it with this solution:
[moved in the answers]

It is possible to tell the controller to halt inside the not_found function?

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails/4983354#4983354

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like to use exception throwing, and then use ActionController's `rescue_from`.

Example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from DataMapper::ObjectNotFoundError, :with => :not_found

  def not_found
    render file => "public/404.html", status => 404, layout => false
  end
end

class PostsController
  def show
    @post = Post.get!(params[:id]) # This will throw an DataMapper::ObjectNotFoundError if it can't be found
    @comments = @post.comments
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Done 'the old Merb way':

```
class ApplicationController
  def not_found
    render file: "public/404.html", status: 404, layout: false
  end
end

class PostsController
  def show
    @post = Post.get(params[:id])
    not_found; return false if @post.nil?
    @comments = @post.comments
  end
end
```

again: It is possible to tell the controller to halt inside the not_found function instead of explicitly calling 'return false' in the show action?

edit: thanx to Francois that found a better solution:

```
class PostsController
  def show
    @post = Post.get(params[:id])
    return not_found if @post.nil?
    @comments = @post.comments
  end
end
```

Comment: This answer is syntactically incorrect, but Rails will stop automatic rendering if something already rendered. You should do

    return not_found if @post.nil?

Comment: You're right! return not_found works and it feels much better. But my answer is working properly and is syntactically correct. Anyway thanks for the guess, I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

[As DM documentation says](http://datamapper.org/docs/find), you can use `#get!`