# rails 3 show 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

how to render 404 instead **NoMethodError in People#show** error

the code

```
def show
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @person }
  end
end
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails/4983354#4983354

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NoMethodError will render a 500 in production mode, however if you want to also render a 404 status in the headers in development mode, you can do the following:

```
 redirect_to :status => 404
```

To render the standard 404 page, you can check out the top answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails)

Comment: oh.nice. NoMethodError will render a 404 in production mode

Comment: I'm sorry, it actually renders a 500 error. Either way, it's more graceful than what you see in development mode.

Comment: so,how to render 404 ?i dont want my user see 500 error page.

Comment: You can see the link I included in the answer. Basically you try catch the error and render a 404 as seen in the link above.

Comment: what im doing is put `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
    render '404'
  end`

in application_controller. but is this the correct way?is this how the rails handle recordnotfound error?