# Conventions for handling URL errors in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications

I am working on a Ruby on Rails app which which has the following path to view a user's page

```
/pics/user/:id
```

:id being the generated id attribute.  My question is that is the proper way for the the app to deal with a number that is not a user id in the place of :id.

The methods I was considering are; creating an Error page and redirect to it or redirecting to another page (in this case a page with the list of all the users) and generating an error message.   Are either of these ideas correct, or should I do something else entirely?
My goal is to adhere to proper ruby on rails and web conventions as closely as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you will be doing `Model.find(params[:id])` and that will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` that is to make the web server send a `404 Not Found` response.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, do you mean I alert the server informing it of the kind of error it is (404 in this case), and then have the server handle it?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I think you should *really* do is set the status of your response to 404 (pass `:status => 404` to render.

Whether your 404 page is just a dumb 'sorry nothing found' page or something more helpful (e.g. with suggestions of what the user might have wanted) is up to you

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method, although I think some RoR purists would argue that this isn't the proper way to do it... but it does work, very nicely. I much prefer this method over a useless 404 page:

**users_controller.rb**

```
  before_filter :get_user, :only => [:show, :edit, :create, :update]

  # ... all your methods ...

  private
    def get_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        redirect_to users_path, :alert => "User not found" and return false
    end
```

Comment: What about this method would upset ROR purists?

Comment: The issue with redirecting to an index page on errors is that you do not get to set a proper status code. If you eventually want to use your controllers as a webservice, it is better to have them act in a RESTful way, which includes using error status codes on errors and not redirecting. See this answer for a railsy way to do it by using the bang methods which will raise RecordNotFound exceptions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails