# How to test render :file => 'public/404.html' in Rspec 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have following code in an action:

```
render :file => 'public/404.html' and return
```

This works fine in the browser. I have written the following rspec example to test this:

```
  it "renders 404" do
    get :new
    response.should render_template('public/404.html')
  end
```

Running this example results in the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: response.should render_template('public/404.html')
   Expected block to return true value.
```

I have also tried `response.should render_template(:file => 'public/404.html')` but that too results in an error.

How should I test this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use:

```
response.should render_template(:file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html")
```

Comment: This doesn't work:
    render_template(:file => "bogus file")
passes.

Comment: Works for me RSpec 3.2, Rails 4.2

Answer (score 5):

if you want to show a 404 page, remember to set the status code. this is also what i would test: `it { should respond_with :not_found }`

instead of rendering the public/404 directly, there are better ways of doing this. have a look at this answer: [How to redirect to a 404 in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails)

Comment: What if it is any other page and not 404.html (or 502.html) specifically? For example, depending on some parameter, I want to show different landing pages to different users.

Comment: i would put this in the router and write routing tests for it.