# ruby on rails: how to restrict nested routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a company model, and a company can have many locations, so I have routes set up like so:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :locations
end
```

I'd like to be able to add a new location to a company at the route `companies/:company_id/locations/new` , however this page is still accessible if I go to a company that does not exist, like so `companies/99999999/locations/new`.

How can I make this page only accessible when the company id exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a before_filter to your locations controller (you're going to need to retrieve the parent company anyways for nested forms and links):

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :get_company    

  def get_company
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  end   

end
```

This way navigating to a Location route under an erroneous Company ID will produce the typical id not found exception which you would normally see if it wasn't a nested resource. Typically you would handle this exception in your application controller and redirect to a 404 page.

Comment: By convention, I've always used `find_company`, but yes, this is the way to go. `get_company` will raise a 404 error if you try to route to an invalid company, which is exactly what you would expect from the client's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want something defined in routes.rb itself, but I'd  just validate the existence of the company in the controller's action (and render a 404, if that's what you want, as explained in [How to redirect to a 404 in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails) )