# How to share a controller action for nested routes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, when I need:

```
/comments
```

and

```
/posts/1/comments
```

How do I best organize CommentsController? E.g. let the routes share the index actions, or work with 2 controllers?

Comment: Hmm.. sorry, this question was poorly formulated. My problem is that if @post is not found, \@comments will be empty, but response (200 OK). However, I would need 404 (not found), if \@post is empty. How to share that action in the controller?

Comment: In the code I gave you, I was thinking that if \@post is not found, then you'll have every comments from every posts in \@comments, not that it would be empty... But you can raise a 404 in this case if you want, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work with only one controller.

I would go with a `before_filter` to check if the `post_id` param is present:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_post, only: [:index]

  def index
    if @post.present?
      ## Some stuff
    else
      ## Other stuff
    end
  end

  private

    def find_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) unless params[:post_id].nil?
    end
end
```

And have in your routes (with the constraints of your choice) :

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
resources :comments
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want `/comments` only for `show` and `index` actions, right? Otherwise the `post` params will be lost when creating or updating a `comment`.

In your `routes.rb` you can have something like:

```
resources : posts do
  resources :comments
end
resources :comments, :only => [:index, :show]
```

In your form:

```
form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f|
```

And in your controller, make sure you find the `post` before dealing with the `comments` (for `new`, `edit`, `create` and `update`, such as:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post...
```

Comment: thanks. So, I understand the routes parts I think, but I am not sure about this:  "in your controller, make sure you always find the post before dealing with the comments", meaning, if @post.present?; @post.comments; else; Comment.all; end ? I am just not sure if I'd better return a [] for comments when @post is nil. Hmm.. does it make sense? thanks!

Comment: one post has many comments, so url for creating and editing must have the full path `/posts/1/comments`, otherwise a comment will not be linked to the post. For this reason you must find the post that will receive a comment: `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do almost anything you want with rails routes.

**routes.rb**

```
match 'posts/:id/comments', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'comments'}

resources :posts do

   member do
    get "comments"
   end
 end
```