# Only enable action when model has certain attribute set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.2.11.  I have an action (show) that I would like to disable if a certain attribute in the model is not set.  Right now I am dealing with this directly in the action:

```
def show
    @model = Model.find(params[:id])
    if !@model.attribute
        raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Something bad happened')
    end
end
```

Is this acceptable or is there a better way of handling this situation?  I would like the behavior to be the same as when a user tries to access a non-existent record.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use that logic in a **before_filter**, so your show action will be clean:

```
before_filter :check_attribute

...

def show
  # you can use straight @model here

end
...

private

def check_attribute
  @model = Model.find(params[:id])
  if !@model.attribute
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Something bad happened')
  end
end
```

In this way you can use it also for other actions.

Comment: I think you mean "before_filter"

Comment: Additionally you can limit the methods this filter applies to using the `only` or `except` options on the filter: `before_filter :check_attribute, :only => :show`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is acceptable. I would personally write the conditionally as a one-liner.

```
raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Something bad happened') unless @model.attribute?
```

A good resource for alternative methods for handling `:not_found` response is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails).