# Using respond_with to serve 404?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-codes, respond-with

I'm trying to serve up a custom 404 response in rails, but I'm not sure how to give the :status to a `respond_with` function.

I know with `render`, I can do something like this:

```
render :status => :not_found, :json => {:response =>"There weren't any results"}
```

How can I do something like that with `respond_with`? Is there even a way to set status codes with `respond_with`?

The only reason I'm using `respond_with` is because, to my understanding, it is proper protocol to use `respond_with` when you've started with `respond_to`. If that isn't correct and I should be using `render`, please let me know!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html#label-Custom+options); `respond_with` takes `:status` as an option.

```
respond_with(@user, status: :not_found) do |format|
  format.json { response: "There weren't any results" }
end
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure how I missed your answer. Thank you so much! That's perfect. Unfortunately, I'm new to ruby and I was looking for `respond_with` in the docs and not `Responder`. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of set a specific 404 status in your response, you could just raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception and it has the same effect. [Check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4983354/895789)

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, but with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` will not allow for custom responses. I know that wasn't very clear in my question, but I do appreciate the response as its helpful to know. Thank you!

Comment: The problem with raising `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` is that it will be logged as an exception and depending on your API it isn't an exception. Maybe you only want to check if a resource exists. For e.g. if the cart doesn't exist (not_found), create it, basically try a get to show, if it returns not_found, make a post to create.