# Rails 4 using rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found for Guest User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I've seen many posts about `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found`, along with the companion method:

```
def record_not_found
  redirect_to action: :show
end
```

This is my first time implementing this, so I'm wondering why I keep getting `This webpage has a redirect loop` or that my params are incorrect for that route (within the `record_not_found` method).

When a guest user time reaches a preset timeout limit, the user record will have the `#destroy` method called on it--even if the guest is still within the app.  The guest user has not yet inputted email/password, and the `guest` column in the `users` table is set to `true`.  (I actually want a guest to be able to Register w/ email, etc from within the app, transferring whatever data/dependencies the guest user object had acquired to the newly created permanent user.)

I've been putting them in my individual controllers, which I know is not DRY...I'd tried this in `ApplicationController` and kept getting the `This webpage has a redirect loop`, but I'm also now getting it in my individual controllers, so I guess that wasn't the problem.

Here is an example from my `lessons_controller.rb`...

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_user, :only => [:show]

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found

  def show
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
    @assessment = @lesson.provide_assessment_object
    if @assessment
      @assessment.make_sure_choices_are_instantiated(current_user)
    end
  end

  private

    def record_not_found
      redirect_to controller: :lessons, action: :show, id: params[:id]
    end 

end
```

My great preference would be to have all the `record_not_found` methods (hopefully eventually all DRYed up within `ApplicationController`) to `redirect_to` the `front` page which doesn't require a user session.

Any help on this would be most appreciate!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, you try to find a lesson x, find throws an error basically saying that the lesson you searching for does not exists and in `record_not_found ` you redirect to the same lesson x and you get a redirect loop.

Comment: What is your question? As @cristian stated, the redirect loop is caused by rescuing the exception and then calling the same code that raises the same exception, thus looping forever.

Comment: Exactly what cristian said.

You've defined an action for `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` that redirects to the `show` action of what could not be found.

The show action in turn is going to look for for a certain `app` in this case. But it  can't find it so it raises  the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception again looping the entire application.

It is considered bad practice to render `404` page when this occurs.
Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails

Comment: I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails and tried this in `ApplicationController`, but now I get the `NameError ` `uninitialized constant ActionController::RecordNotFound`
It seems like this is a step in the right direction though.  Thanks!