# Confusing situation with 'redirect_to' in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I tried to make a redirect to the '404' page.
In my filter I made a mistake and wrote:

```
redirect_to '404'
```

When i tested this, I had a strange result:
It seems like my browser was redirrected me back(I saw page, where I was before), like I'm wrote:

```
redirect_to :back
```

There are links to my *picture* about that:
http://oi58.tinypic.com/j62xht.jpg
http://itmages.ru/image/view/2873810/38c73083

**My browser**: Mozila Firefox 39.0.3

And i have a question: "Why it works?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of redirecting to the 404 page, I would instead raise an error that Rails catches and automatically responds with a 404.

```
raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
```

Check out this question: [How to redirect to a 404 in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails)

With respect to why it's sending you back, I'd look at the `redirect_to` documentation. It seems like it's just creating a new request that happens to hit the same place you came from.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to

Comment: Thanks for the good tip, i will use it, but my question is "why my mistake works?"

Comment: I'd want to see your other routes/server log to figure that out, but the documentation could probably help: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to

Comment: There is server log:
http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?prt1pfvrae4a

Comment: Looks like your `check_access` before filter is sending them to the same page

Comment: Yes, chech_access did it with: "redirect_to '404‘''. It's incorrect syntax for this method. After that, i asked myself: ‘Why this hack works?‘ Anyway, this is a bad way.  P.s. If I have problems in English?