# Rails generic not found controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my controller I have this code in one of my actions:

```
begin
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.destroy
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  render :json => {"status" => "404", "message" => "User with id #{params[:id]} not found"}
  return
end
```

And is working fine, but I dont want to copy paste it to all the methods which require to run a Select query.

So I found this answer [How to redirect to a 404 in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails)

And then tried slightly different since I am rendering JSON API endpoints instead templates.
Note also I dont know if that params[:id] will be defined there.

```
  def not_found
    render :json => {"status" => "404", "message" => "User with id #{params[:id]} not found"}
  end
```

Anyway I modified the query with:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]) or not_found
```

But is still raising the ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception.

Also would it be possible to create a generic not_found action which I can use in all the controllers which I can pass it the id parameter and the type of the Object?

Like some generic 404, 500, 400, 200 methods which render JSON responses  where I can just pass some parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  rescue_from in your ApplicationController：

```
class ApplicationController
     rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :show_not_found_errors

     # All the information about the exception is in the parameter: exception
     def show_not_found_errors(exception)
        render json: {error: exception.message}, status: :not_found
     end
end
```

Thus, any ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound will be rescued with show_not_found_errors method. Add these codes in ApplicationController, and it will works for all the others controllers which is inherited from ApplicationController.

Comment: Thanks for your response! With your code I am receiving now an empty JSON when the object is not found, should I replace render json: exception, status: :not_found with my code?

Comment: I see, is there a way I can extend this code to all the controllers of my application? or must I define them in all of them.

Comment: @lapinkoira just in ApplicationController, check my update.

Comment: mm alright, do you think it would be possible to detect which kind of object raised the exception? So it can write down User not found... Collection not found... etc

Comment: All the informations you need is in the params: exception, it a instance of ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, try exception.message as my update.