# How do I redirect to 404 page when a user record does not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, redirect

e.g I have one model (User model). When user signsup for an account, there is an email sent to alert user that his/her account has been activated. In this case, if an admin deletes user record and then user clicks the link from the email to see his or her profile, it will show error. So, I want to check if a user record exists or not. if it does not exist, user should be redirected to 404 page.

I have tried the code below but it not working. [this is the following example that i have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4983354/8068059)

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) or raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

So, is there a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])

  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') if @user.blank?
end
```

Comment: Did you mean `.find_by_id`? `User.find` will throw exception anyway, you won't be able to check `@user.blank?`

Comment: @Parinha try with updatad answer.

Comment: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @Gerry can you show me how to raise this error in application controller? e.g if any record does not exist -> it automatically redirect to or raise as record no found to 404 page.

Comment: It is better to `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`, because it is dedicated error for that scenario

Answer (score 7):

It's quite simple, you just need to `render` rails default `404` page or your customized one..

In your application controller,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # rest of your application controller code

 def content_not_found
   render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", layout: true, status: :not_found
 end
end
```

Then, call it from any controller you wish. In you case,

```
def show
  if (@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id]).present?
    # do your stuff
  else
    content_not_found
  end
end
```

I don't like exceptions, and I try to avoid them as much as possible ;)

Comment: I also prefer to avoid exceptions whenever possible, specially when they control flow.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def show
  if (@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])).present?
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
  else
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want at application level...

In application controller, add the following...

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_404

def render_404
  render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html",  :status => 404
end
```

In user Controller you can just say,

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

If you want this just at single controller level,

In User controller, do the following

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
rescue ActionController::RoutingError
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of

## Rails 3 and up

```
render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html",  :status => 404
```

If you want to make use of application controller then you can try to write two points given below in application controller file:

1) create render_404 action:

```
  def render_404
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", status: 404 }
    end
  end
```

2) `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404 action`

As you are making use of 'show' action

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

If no record found(no user found with params[:id]) then automatically there will be 404.

Comment: how can i redirect all records that not exist to 404 page? i prefer in application controller.