# How do I render a 404 without actually rendering my web page?

Tags: controller, http-status-code-404, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I would like to render a default 404 page on a certain condition in my Rails 5.1 app.  I have this in my controller

```
  def index
    ...
    if worker
    ...
    else
      puts "page not found"
      render :status => 404
    end
  end
```

However, even if the condition if met (my 404 branch is called), Rails is still trying to render my index.htrml.erb page, which is resulting in other errors because the expected model attributes are not there.  Is there a way I can have a 404 status code returned without a page being rendered?

Comment: Probably looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is rendering public/404 with status code 404, you have any specific layout for the 404-page **layout:  true** otherwise **layout: false**. then return a false value

```
render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404", layout: false, status: 404
return false
```

Comment: Thx.  So if I have my own 404 page defined in Apache will my throwing the 404 status from teh Rails app invoke allow my Apache 404 page to be rendered?

Comment: `render nothing: true, layout: false, status: 404` this will return 404 status to the HTTP server, in your case Apache. In production, apache will show configured 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is:

```
render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404", layout: true, status: :not_found
```

Another way is to raise an error which will caught as 404 by rails

Among the errors are: `ActionController::RoutingError`, `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` or `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

Having the method `not_found`, it can be called when it's needed

```
def not_found
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end

def index
  ...
  if worker
  ...
  else
    puts "page not found"
    not_found
  end
end
```

For other formats you can use just `head :not_found`

Comment: If you are using directly the first option, without being in a method or last in the method, use it like `render .... and return`