# How to define custom error codes for api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, error-code

I want to define custom error codes in my api response like

```
{ status: 401,message: "Authentication issue",code: 1000}
```

I want to define this 1000 code in my app with some documentation of explanation. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplication question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: its not duplicate...thats a different question

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to set a 404 page. There are a lot of tutorials and question here on SO teaching how to do that, as the link above.

Comment: No i want to send some sort of information from code

Comment: what do you mean by `define` ? Do you want to put some extras infos for coding purpose ? Or is it for your end-user ?

Comment: for end user who will use api's

Comment: Do you want create a customize template/view page that when the end user get the status 401 the template/view will be display?

Comment: @HaseebAhmad Did you check my answer? if it doesn't help so please explain more about your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define your custom exception:

```
class API::Unauthorized < StandardError
  attr_reader :code

  def initialize(code)
    super
    @code = code
  end
end
```

Then in your APIController, use [rescue_from](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from), so add the following:

```
rescue_from StandardError, :with => :exception_handler

def exception_handler(exception)
  if exception.is_a? API::Unauthorized
    render json: { status: 401, message: "Authentication issue", code: exception.code }, status: unauthorized
  end
end
```

Now you can throw different exception codes based on your implementation by:

```
raise API::Unauthorized.new(1000)
```